# Opencypher Neptune db create ~id field with custom value using opencypher

Tags: graph, amazon-neptune

I want to set my own id to the node I create using opencypher
I am using below query

```
CREATE (n:person {ID:'myid', id: 'abc',name:'abcname'})
```

it created below row

```
{'~id': '7638bbd4-900d-4b15-b451-5eb848a3db19', '~entityType': 'node', '~labels': ['person'], '~properties': {'ID': 'myid', 'id': 'abc', 'name': 'abcname'}}
```

but instead I want it to create as below

```
{'~id': 'myid', '~entityType': 'node', '~labels': ['person'], '~properties': {'name': 'abcname'}}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.2.0.2 (Nov 22), Neptune supports custom id properties (`~id` ) in openCypher statements, including `CREATE`, `MERGE`, `MATCH`:

```
CREATE (n {`~id`: 'fromNode', name: 'john'})
  -[:knows {`~id`: 'john-knows->jim', since: 2020}]
  ->(m {`~id`: 'toNode', name: 'jim'})

MATCH (n {`~id`: 'id1'})
RETURN n

MATCH (n {name: 'john'}), (m {name: 'jim'})
MERGE (n)-[r {`~id`: 'john->jim'}]->(m)
RETURN r
```

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/feature-opencypher-compliance.html#opencypher-compliance-custom-ids)

[Announcement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.2.0.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

The openCypher specification does not allow for specifying the `~id` value for a node, so there is not a way to do this in Neptune currently.  Neptune does support setting this value using Gremlin:

```
g.addV('person').property(T.id, 'myid').property('id', 'abc').property('name', 'abcname')
```

Which can then be queried using openCypher:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n)='myid' RETURN n
```

Updated 7/5/2023:

The answer provided by @varontron is the preferred answer.  As they stated, setting the ID value is now supported as of 1.2.0.2 version of Neptune.

Comment: I see that various drive behaves differently . I am trying CypherGremlinClient.submit("MATCH p=(n)-[r]->(d) WHERE ID(n) = '" + wgiId + "' RETURN n,r") which gives me all details i need but it is very slow. another way or running query very fast but it does not return all attributes. Driver.session.beginTransaction().run("MATCH p=(n)-[r]->(d) WHERE ID(n) = '" + wgiId + "' RETURN n,r") does not give me all attributes, like ~label and ~id

Comment: With Neptune, you can use Gremlin and openCypher interchangeably on the same data.  Due to the limitations of the openCypher spec discussed above, you can specify the `id` value with a Gremlin query but still use openCypher to perform the read queries, which will provide you the information you are requesting.  I would steer away from using the translation of the driver.